# C# Issue with deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a binary file generated from another software. Its generating it by serializing object. But when I am trying to deserialize it, I am getting only a single header object. I am not sure how they are storing their objects into the file but I am sure there are more than one object. So my question is - is there any option in .net to get all serialized objects from a single file?

Thanks

I am using this code:

```
        Stream sr = new FileStream("C:\\abc.bin", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        object o = formatter.Deserialize(sr);
```

Comment: How did you serialize the object?

Comment: You sure you serialized the same object?

Comment: if you don't know how it's serialized, you can't deserialize it.

Comment: Can you provide your `abc.bin` file?

Comment: There isn't just one way to serialize objects that everyone conforms to -- as @tenfour mentioned, if you don't know exactly how the objects are written out, you have a very low chance of being able to read them in.  BinaryFormatter is not some kind of silver bullet.

Comment: Was it even serialised with BinaryFormatter? You need to know exactly how it was serialized to deserialize it.

Comment: I dont actually how it is serialized. But it can retrieve first object. @Munim-My file is too big to share here, its 139 mb.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to deserialize it you need to reference the assembly containing the classes that were serialized. Otherwise how would .NET know how to build the objects? So that, in effect, means you need to know what went in, to be able to get it out again.

If they're only using .NET types, you still need to reference the correct .NET assemblies. Of course they could be using only types in System, but more than likely they're serializing some custom objects from a library you need to reference.

Comment: @Mithon- I have already added the assembly. As I told before its deserializing it successfully, I mean no error but it seems it does not deserializing the whole file. Take a look at this link, you will understand what I am talking about http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825397.aspx Its a tbin file

Comment: Ah. I didn't get that part. Afaik there's no method to serialise to an object-array. However you should be able to simply test if you're at the end of the stream, and keep deserializing untill you are.